# Pass large amount of data through res.render (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to pass an object with about as many as 3000 names through the .render function.

Checked everything and came down to conclusion it's not the database, nor the page and it's the data 'copying', I assume, over to the response. I saw someone suggested something about AJAX and changing the response, 10 names at a time, but I'm afraid I am not entirely sure how to execute it..
Code is not on my machine so will try my best to depict it:

> in route.js

```
import addRequestPageController from "../controllers/addRequestPageController"

app.get('/add_request', ... , addRequestPageController.addRequest)
```

> in addRequestPageController.js

```
import DBConnection from "../configs/connectDB" // This is where the mysql DB connection is configured

let addRequest = function(req, res) {
var obj = {}
try {

 DBConnection.query(..(a query brings 50~ names).., function(err, rows) {
     if (err) {
        res.render("error.ejs")
     } else { // No errors
         obj.docNames = rows
         // Each doctor has firstName and lastName attributes
         res.render("addRequest.ejs", obj)
     }
 })

 DBConnection.query(..(query-3000 rows with drug names, ratings).., function(err, rows) {
     if (err) {
        res.render("error.ejs")
     } else { // No errors
         obj.drugNames = rows
         // Each drug has it's name(varchar) and rating (float value)
         res.render("addRequest.ejs", obj)
     }
 })

} catch{...}

}

module.exports = {
addRequest: addRequest
}
```

adding the addRequest.ejs for further reference-

> in addRequest.ejs

```
...


<select name="docNames" id="docNames">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <% docNames.forEach(function(doc) { %>
      <!-- Start of forEach -->
      <option value="<% doc.firstName + " " + doc.lastName %>">
      <!-- that was to put a value of the doctor's name -->
      <% doc.firstName + " " + doc.lastName %>
      <!-- and that was to put the actual value the user sees -->
      </option>
      <!-- End of forEach -->
      <% }) %> 
</select>

<select name="drugNames" id="drugNames">
     <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
     <% drugNames.forEach(function(drug) { %> 
     <!-- Start of forEach -->
     <option value="<% drug.drug_name %>">
     <!-- that was to put a value of the drug's name -->
     <% drug.drug_name + " and rating of : " + drug.rating %>
     <!-- that was to put the actual value the user sees -->
     </option>
     <!-- End of forEach -->
     <% }) %> 
</select>

...
```

So basically I am passing parameters to the page, but it stucks at loading and giving me no errors.
Is there a way to change only addRequest to get the desired outcome?

edit: added addRequest.ejs, and edited the addRequestPageController.js.
I did however tried to render a different page with nothing in it, and it still failed to load.. feelsbadman

Comment: why do you want to pass a large number of data to render? this is not the best practice

Comment: Can you show what `addReqest.ejs` is doing with all that data?

Comment: 3000 names is really not very much data compared to even a basic image.  If the names average 30 bytes in length, you'd still have less than 90k of data.  There should be no problem sending that.  What exact problem are you experiencing?  Stuck at loading is likely caused by something else.  For reference, the CNN home page is over 1MB.

Comment: Just edited the post @Bergi , although as I mentioned below, I tried rendering a different page with no use of 'docNames' or 'drugNames', to no avail ):
I thank you guys so much..

Comment: @jfriend00 I really hope it's something I did over at the ejs, so your message gives me hope

Comment: One problem I see is that you're trying to call `res.render()` twice for the same request.  Can't do that.  You can only call it once.  You need to gather all the data you need and then call `res.render()` once, passing it all the data it needs.

Comment: Did you check error logs? As @jfriend00 mentioned, you only can call `res.render()` once. You can only send data _once_ to the client, then you're done. You probably got an error that said something along the lines: `Cannot send headers after they are sent.` When your page doesn't load, it's a 500 error you're usually getting.

Comment: By the way, in your EJS when you want to display data to the user, you need to add `=` or `-` after `<%`. Right now you're doing something like `<% drug.drug_name %>`. That's equivalent to typing the variable in your regular JavaScript without doing anything with it. To display the data you need to add an equal sign: `<%= drug.drug_name %>` or `<%- drug.drug_name %>` (`-` does not escape characters while `=` does).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `res.render()` twice and it's a race condition for which one finishes first.  And, the first one to finish will only have one piece of data in it, not both.  The first call to `res.render()` will likely fail since your template refers to both sets of data, but the first call to `res.render()` will onlky have one of the two properties set in `obj`.  The second call to `res.render()` will be ignored by Express because you can only call it once.  You should see an error in your log somewhere.

You need to collect all the data for the template first so you have it call before you call `res.render()` once passing it all the data it needs.  Here's one way to do that:

```
import DBConnection from "../configs/connectDB" // This is where the mysql DB connection is configured

export function addRequest(req, res) {
    DBConnection.query(..(a query brings 50~names).., function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.render("error.ejs");
        } else { // No errors
            const obj = { docNames: rows };
            // Each doctor has firstName and lastName attributes
            DBConnection.query(..(query - 3000 rows with drug names, ratings).., function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.render("error.ejs");
                } else { // No errors
                    obj.drugNames = rows
                    // Each drug has it's name(varchar) and rating (float value)
                    res.render("addRequest.ejs", obj)
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

---

Also, I'm quite confused why you're using `import` to load the database module, but then using `module.exports`.  Those two do not go together.  Pick one module module or the other, not a mix of the two.  `import` would go with `export` and `require()` would go with `module.exports`.  This needs to also be fixed and you need to properly specify to nodejs either with a `.mjs` file extension or with `type: "module"` in package.json if you're trying to use an ESM module with `import` and `export`.

---

And note, that I'm always logging an error that results in an error returned from the request.  If such an error happens and the client reports an error page, the first thing you're going to need to know is why that error occurred so you will want that info in your server logs.

And, if you used the promise interface to your database instead of the plain callback interface, you could run these two queries in parallel with `Promise.all()` and likely produce the result quicker than this mechanism of doing the requests serially.  While it's possible to program these requests in parallel without promises, it's a pain to get right (and with proper error handling) and promises are the supported mechanism in the language for doing so and they make it a lot easier.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `import` and `export` is only allowed with the `mjs` file extension or specifying as so in `package.json`: `type: "module"`; otherwise it's `require()` and `exports`/`module.exports`.

Comment: "*and the second time without the `docNames` data.*" - actually no, the second call will have both query results, since it's the same `obj`. But of course writing the http response a second time will fail. OP really should be getting errors in their server log.

Comment: @Bergi - Well actually, it's a race condition as both Db calls are running in parallel.  Who knows which one will finish first.  The first one to finish will only have one piece of data in `obj` and will call `res.render()` with that.  The second call to `res.render()` will be ignored.  I've edited my answer to elaborate on this state.  Either way, they have to get all the data first and then call `res.render()` just once with all the data.

Comment: Yes, I meant the second call to the callback / the second call to `res.render` not the second one in source order :-)